# Preserve special characters during tokenization

Tags: elasticsearch

The following settings works for us  however to see better results we 
          would like to preserve special characters. can someone suggest what 
          changes below settings required to preserve special characters?
           The following settings works for us  however to see better results we 
          would like to `preserve special characters. can someone suggest what 
          changes below settings required to preserve special characters?

```
      we would like to preserve following special characters...
      + - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /

       settingsSimple() {
      curl -XPUT "$es_host:9200/$INDEX/" --data-binary @- <<EOF 
      {
       "settings": {
        "index": {
        "number_of_shards": $(($(curl -s $es_hostname:9200/_cat/nodes | wc -  
         l)*2)),
         "number_of_replicas": 0,
         "refresh_interval": "-1"
     },
      "analysis": {
       "char_filter": {
          "chr_decoder": {
              "type": "mapping",
             "mappings": [
        "2=>tu",
        "@=>a",
        "$=>s",
        ".=>-",
        "’=> ",
        ":=> ",
        "!=> "
      ],
      "preserve_original": true
     },
     "chr_decoder2": {
      "type": "mapping",
      "mappings": [
        "2=>tu",
        "@=>a",
        "$=>s"
      ],
      "preserve_original": true
    },
    "dash_remover": {
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "pattern": "-",
      "replacement": ""
    }
   },
  "analyzer": {
    "all_analyzer": {
      "char_filter": [
        "chr_decoder",
        "dash_remover"
      ],
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "ascii_folding",
        "stop_filter"
      ]
    },
    "name_analyzer": {
      "char_filter": [
        "chr_decoder2"
      ],
      "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
      ]
    },
    "keep_analyzer": {
      "char_filter": [
        "chr_decoder2"
      ],
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "ascii_folding": {
      "type": "asciifolding",
      "preserve_original": false
    },
    "stop_filter": {
      "type": "stop",
      "stopwords": [
        "and",
        "the"
      ]
    },
    "shingle_filter": {
      "type": "shingle",
      "min_shingle_size": 2,
      "max_shingle_size": 3,
      "output_unigrams": true,
      "token_separator": " ",
      "filler_token": " "
    }
  },
  "tokenizer": {
    "ngram_tokenizer": {
      "type": "edgeNGram",
      "min_gram": "2",
      "max_gram": "20",
      "token_chars": [
        "letter",
        "digit"
      ],
      "preserve_original": true
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
   EOF
   }   

  Query I use follows here:
  {
    "from" : 0,
    "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
    "function_score" : {
    "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [ {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "!Mayday!",
          "fields" : [ "enm^8", "pnm^12", "upnm^31", "_all^10" ],
          "default_operator" : "and",
          "analyzer" : "all_analyzer"
        }
      }, {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "!Mayday!",
          "fields" : [ "_all^8", "enm^8", "pnm^12", "upnm^31" ],
          "default_operator" : "and",
          "analyzer" : "keep_analyzer"
        }
      } ]
    }
    },
    "filter" : {
    "terms" : {
      "sml" : [ "0" ]
     }
    },
     "functions" : [ {
      "field_value_factor" : {
      "field" : "pop",
      "factor" : 6.0,
      "missing" : 0.0,
      "modifier" : "none"
      }
      } ],
   "boost_mode" : "sum"
      }
      },
      "fields" : [ "uid", "enm", "pid", "upid", "pnm", "rd", "upnm" ]
       }
```

Comment: can you show us a sample string and what is currently happening and what would you like to change?

Comment: currently if I search for !Mayday! , it will be listed in search result(4 or 5 position) but not in first place and we replacing ! with space. since we explicitly searching for "!Mayday!" string, we expect "!Mayday!" in first place in search result.

Comment: can you post your current query? also if '!Mayday!' is in 4th position what is in top 3?

Comment: first 3 response strings are Mayday Parade ,Mayday, MayDay! x Murs. It's not allowing me to paste my complete query here so added here part of it

Comment: "query" : {
    "function_score" : {
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [ {
            "query_string" : {
              "query" : "!Mayday!",
              "fields" : [ "enm^8", "pnm^12", "upnm^31", "_all^10" ],
              "default_operator" : "and",
              "analyzer" : "all_analyzer"
            }
          },

Comment: can you try multi fields approach? analyze your field with both custom analyzer and index:not_analyzed and then give higher boost to not_analyzed field?

Comment: Chintan, I have updated my question with full query, please take a look. I think we already doing what you mentioned above. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Since I am using "whitespace" tokenizer it preserve all special characters:

I have created the index template by following. 
All inputs, aggregations and queries then are properly showing my variables.

```
PUT _template/tracking_all
{
  "template": "tracking*",
  "version": 1,
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
           "type": "custom",
           "filter": [ "lowercase" ],
           "tokenizer": "whitespace"
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```